# GIFV: How do I create high quality animated GIFs?

Tags: video, animation, gif

I am planning to create high quality animated gif(v)s from my dslr video files.

How do I do this?

I am running a mac.

EDIT: http://imgur.com/blog/2014/10/09/introducing-gifv/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GIFV is an imaginary format, it's just an illusion. You upload a GIF, the site converts it to MP4 (H.264), and then uses HTML5 to loop the video like a GIF.

**For example:**

```
<video width="500" height="200" controls loop video controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://example.com/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

If your goal is to upload to Imgur.com then you currently need to upload as GIF, but they may eventually add support for MP4 uploads.

If your goal is create GIFV equivalent files on your home computer for your usage, just use a video converter like Handbrake to convert to MP4 with H.264 encoding. The videos will not loop unless you play them back in a program capable of looping, because they are just video files.